# HttpClient+WebApi+Multiple Post + multiple parametres

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to asp.net, I encountered a small problem, i create a new webapi controller in MVC project, when i try to get response from this controlle i get  404 error :s

here is the code of controler used :

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string Auth(string number, string password)
        {
            ....
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string SendSms(string smsTo, string content)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

WebApiConfig :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and here the code c# :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:66893");
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("number", "login"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "password")
            });
                var result = client.PostAsync("/api/sms/auth", content).Result;
                string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
            }
```

when i try localhost:66893/api/sms/auth?number=xxx&password=xxx in XHR Poster i get the result :s

plz help 
thx a lot

Comment: Since you're doing a POST you will need to use something like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to send the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But your route doesn't include an action. Shouldn't it be:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Answer (score 1):

Your client posts to "/api/sms/auth" but since you named your controller **SampleController** it should be "/api/***sample***/auth".

This is because Web API adds "Controller" to the value of the {controller} variable to find the controller.